# How can I skip or allow or block browser popup in selenium with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

[image: Allow Block]

How can I skip or allow or block browser alert message in selenium with python3 ?

I'm using PyCharm

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please describe in more detail the problem you're experiencing and the outcome you desire. Please also include the code you already have.

Comment: See [Handle notifications in Python + Selenium Chrome WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400934/handle-notifications-in-python-selenium-chrome-webdriver)

Comment: You can set a preference for this, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44471872/5747944). There are also other solutions provided in that same question, though not all of them are for Python, the Python equivalent should be possible.