# how to disable chrome notifications popup in selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, browser, notifications, alerts

```
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    opt = Options()
    opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
    opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {\
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications":1
        })
```

this isn't working Help
How can I turn off Browser Notification In selenium using python

Comment: what kind of notifications? Those allow/block notifications types?

Comment: yes allow/block types

Comment: Like notification allow and disallow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications value need to be set to 2 instead of 1

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Reference:-  [Handle notifications in Python + Selenium Chrome WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400934/handle-notifications-in-python-selenium-chrome-webdriver)